# Prove that if $\sigma_x(n) = \sigma_x(m)$ and $\sigma_{-x}(n) = \sigma_{-x}(m)$, then $n=m$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

Only thing I've gotten so far is writing out each individual expression as a product of primes. What do I do next? Also, the function I mean is this one

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Also, $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Here is the expression I have :

\begin{gather}
n = \prod_{i = 1}^r p_i^{a_i} \\
\sigma_{x}(n) = \prod_{i = 1}^r \bigl(1 + p_i^{x} + p_i^{2x} + \dotsc + p_i^{a_ix}\bigr).
\end{gather}

Comment: $D(-x(n))$ ??? ${}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I don't know how to write the actual function.. basically, the sum of the positive divisors of n to the power of -x. It's the function on wikipedia.

Comment: Did you mean $\sigma_{-x}(n) = \sum_{d | n} d^{-x}$ ? Do you know how to compute the coefficients of the Dirichlet series $\zeta(s) \zeta(s+x)$ ? And divisor sums is for $\sum_{n \le x} \sigma_a(n)$

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. And no, I don't know the second thing, or the third.

Comment: You said you got an expression in term of $p | n$ .. So show us

Comment: Added it in the question

Comment: You are funny. Click on edit in the other questions to see the mathjax people type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $x \neq 0$. For $x = 0$ we have $\sigma_x(n) = \sigma_{-x}(n) =  \tau(n)$ and $\tau(m) = \tau(n)$ does not imply $m = n$.

For $x \neq 0$ the involution $d \mapsto \frac{n}{d}$ of the set of divisors of $n$ yields

$$\sigma_{-x}(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} \biggl(\frac{n}{d}\biggr)^{-x} = n^{-x}\sum_{d\mid n} d^x = n^{-x}\sigma_x(n),$$

so $\sigma_x(n) = \sigma_x(m)$ and $\sigma_{-x}(n) = \sigma_{-x}(m)$ yields

$$n^x = \frac{\sigma_x(n)}{\sigma_{-x}(n)} = \frac{\sigma_x(m)}{\sigma_{-x}(m)} = m^x.$$

Since the power function $t \mapsto t^x$ is injective on $(0,+\infty)$ for $x\neq 0$, it follows that $n = m$.

Comment: Thanks! This is really elegant. Could you tell me how you came up with the bijection?

Comment: It is an old trick that is useful in various places. I think I learned it from Hardy and Wright, but I'm not certain. Once one knows the trick, it's just a matter of not forgetting to check whether it helps in a given situation.

Comment: Alright, thanks.